# install dependency in Bitnami Odoo Stack

Tags: python, odoo, bitnami, cups

Hi I am having problem with a python Module installation.
I want to install a python module pycups in bitnami odoo stack v8. but when i try to install it, It is installed in ubuntu's own python directory. How to direct the bitnami's python to look for default python's library?
Also if there is another way to install pycups in bitnami's own stack.
Will it work if i copy and paste the directory of pycups from ubuntu's python directory to bitnami's python directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install an internal dependency in bitnami Odoo stack:

Go to /../odoo-8.0-6/python/bin/
Run from there the executable "python2.7" (Do not run native python shell. i.e. from command prompt or terminal.). Instead run python shell from above directory.

In Python type:

```
from subprocess import call
call("pip install your_dependency_name",shell=True)
```

e.g

```
call("pip install psycopg2",shell=True)
```

It will install package psycopg2 within the do stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can find how to install plugins on Odoo at wiki page:

https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/Bitnami_Odoo#How_to_install_a_plugin_on_Odoo

In addition, you can take a look at this other page for knowing how to load the Bitnami console to use the shipped components, for example Python:

https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/BitNami_console

The file cups.h is needed to install pycups. If you are using Ubuntu you can install the package libcups2-dev with:

```
sudo apt-get install libcups2-dev
```

Then install pycups using pip:

```
sudo pip install pycups
```